# No matching function for call to 'ellipse'

Tags: ios, opencv

I'm using OpenCV and detecting user's body. But I'm getting the error:

> No matching function for call to 'ellipse'

That function is present inside my framework still it's showing the error:

```
// Body Detection

std::vector<cv::Rect> body;
cascade.detectMultiScale(mat, body, 1.1, 2, 18|9, cv::Size(3,7));

std::vector<cv::Rect>::const_iterator rs = body.begin();

for(int j = 0; j<body.size(); j++){
    cv::Point center(body[j].x + body[j].width * 0.5, body[j].y+ + body[j].height * 0.5);
    cv::ellipse(mat, center, Size(body[j].width * 0.5 + body[j].height * 0.5), 0, 0, 360, cv::Scalar(255, 0 , 255), 4, 8, 0);

}
```

[image: Error]

[image]

Comment: You're probably missing a comma inside the `Size` constructor. And probably you need `cv::Size`

Comment: Thanks. It solved my problem. But i'm not getting the results correct. Not even close. Am I doing it correct ?

Comment: What is not correct?

Comment: Detection. Even if I have only full face into camera, it's getting detected which actually it shouldn't. I want to detect whole body only.

Comment: That isn't something that can be answered with this information only. I recommend to ask another question with more details of the code and a few images of expected and actual results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in this line:

```
cv::ellipse(mat, center, Size(body[j].width * 0.5 + body[j].height * 0.5), 0, 0, 360, cv::Scalar(255, 0 , 255), 4, 8, 0);
```

`cv::ellipse` expects a `cv::Size` object, while you're passing a different `Size` object. Also the constructor of `cv::Size` expects two parameters `width` and `height`. You probably are missing a comma to divide the arguments.

So the code should look like:

```
cv::ellipse(mat, center, cv::Size(body[j].width * 0.5, body[j].height * 0.5), 0, 0, 360, cv::Scalar(255, 0 , 255), 4, 8, 0);
```